# How can I enable a certain route access only when a certain condition is true?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

## Goal

I'm trying to block my main login page base on a flag of my `.env` file.
I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

---

## Steps

In my `.env` I've added

`LOGIN_PAGE=true`

Then in my route file

I add that if check

```
if(env('LANDING_PAGE') == true){

    Route::get('/',['as' => 'login', 'uses'=>'AuthController@getSignIn']);
    Route::post('/', 'AuthController@postSignIn');
}
```

---

## Result

`LOGIN_PAGE=fasle`

I go to my log-in page, I got 404 Page not found which is good.

`LOGIN_PAGE=true`

I go to my log-in page, I still got 404 Page not found which is not good. I should see my log-in page.

What did I forget ? How would one and go about and #GOAL

I'm trying to block my main login page base on a flag of my `.env` file.
I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

---

## Steps

In my `.env` I've added

`LOGIN_PAGE=true`

Then in my route file

I add that if check

```
if(env('LANDING_PAGE') == true){

    Route::get('/',['as' => 'login', 'uses'=>'AuthController@getSignIn']);
    Route::post('/', 'AuthController@postSignIn');
}
```

---

## Result

`LOGIN_PAGE=fasle`

I go to my log-in page, I got 404 Page not found which is good.

`LOGIN_PAGE=true`

I go to my log-in page, I still got 404 Page not found which is not good. I should see my log-in page.

How would one enable a certain route access only when a certain condition is true?

Comment: In your .env, you have the setting named LOGIN_PAGE, but in your routes you're checking for LANDING_PAGE.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice to what you are asking is to define a middleware that can be reused wherever and whenver you need it :

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckIsLandingPage
```

Then define the logic behinde your middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckIsLAndingPage
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // your logic here 
        if (env('LANDING_PAGE') == true) {
           return redirect('somewhere');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Read more in the Laravel docs : 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#defining-middleware

Not much has changed in latest 5.5:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware

Comment: I am using laravel 5.1. I also tag my post as `5.1` - Please update your answer to be relevant to that.

Comment: He's linked to the 5.5 docs, but you'd do this the exact same in 5.1. 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#defining-middleware

Comment: Don't use env anywhere other than config files. It will not work properly.
use env in config and then use config where ever you want